# java dice game issues -fast please

Tags: java, methods

Create a dice game where it is player vs computer. The point of the game is to take turns rolling the dice and the first one to reach 100 wins. If either player rolls a 2, their total automatically goes down 2. If they role anything else, it is added to running total. Fist one >= 100 wins. Generate a random number between 0 and 2 to decide who rolls first. If 0, player rolls first, if one, computer rolls first.

I am a novice programmer in high school and am having lots of trouble with this. I figured out how to display the dice rolls individually by listing them all separately. It would be great if someone would show me an easier way because i can't figure out how to find the first one to 100 using that method.

```
public class problemTwo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int d1=(int)(Math.random()*6+1);
        int d2=(int)(Math.random()*6+1);
        int dSum= d1 + d2;
        System.out.println("Player Roll 1 total is ;" +dSum); 

        int d3=(int)(Math.random()*6+1);
        int d4=(int)(Math.random()*6+1);
        int dSum2= d3 + d4;
        System.out.println("Player Roll 2 total is ;" +dSum2); 

        int d5=(int)(Math.random()*6+1);
        int d6=(int)(Math.random()*6+1);
        int dSum3= d5 + d6;
        System.out.println("Player Roll 3 total is ;" +dSum3); 

        int d7=(int)(Math.random()*6+1);
        int d8=(int)(Math.random()*6+1);
        int dSum4= d7 + d8;
        System.out.println("Player Roll 4 total is ;" +dSum4); 

        int d9=(int)(Math.random()*6+1);
        int d10=(int)(Math.random()*6+1);
        int dSum5= d9 + d10;
        System.out.println("Player Roll 5 total is ;" +dSum5); 

        int d11=(int)(Math.random()*6+1);
        int d12=(int)(Math.random()*6+1);
        int dSum6= d11 + d12;
        System.out.println("Player Roll 6 total is ;" +dSum6); 

        int d13=(int)(Math.random()*6+1);
        int d14=(int)(Math.random()*6+1);
        int dSum7= d13 + d14;
        System.out.println("Player Roll 7 total is ;" +dSum7); 

        int d15=(int)(Math.random()*6+1);
        int d16=(int)(Math.random()*6+1);
        int dSum8= d15 + d15;
        System.out.println("Player Roll 8 total is ;" +dSum8); 

        int d17=(int)(Math.random()*6+1);
        int d18=(int)(Math.random()*6+1);
        int dSum9= d17 + d17;
        System.out.println("Player Roll 9 total is ;" +dSum9); 

        int d19=(int)(Math.random()*6+1);
        int d20=(int)(Math.random()*6+1);
        int dSum10= d19 + d20;
        System.out.println("Player Roll 10 total is ;" +dSum10); 

     System.out.println("Roll "+ " total is"  +(dSum + dSum2 + dSum3 + dSum4 + dSum5+ + dSum6+ + dSum7+ + dSum8+ + dSum9+ + dSum10)); 
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "fast please"?

Comment: Please post the code you have already written.

Comment: It seems we are missing a `fastplease` tag .

Comment: how do i upload it?

Comment: Write it like ' code '

Comment: If you are looking for reference, see this dice game made by me: [link](https://github.com/Amitbhave/SnakeAndLadderGame)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html By the way, you have multiple mistakes like `d15 + d15`, which you most likely wouldn't have if you used a loop...

Answer (score 1):

The thing here, is that you are limiting the number of time a dice can be rolled. In your code, each player roll the time 10 times max, which mean that if they score a low on every roll, they will never reach 100.
What you want to do is to use a `while` loop that will run the same code until a condition is reached.
Here is the skeleton, i'll let you figure out the rest ;)

```
while( no player reached a score of 100 ) {
    player 1 roll the dice
    add the result to player 1 score
    player 2 roll the dice
    add the result to player 2 score
}
```

Note that this kind of question isn't well received on this site. What you need to do is understand what part of your code you can't get to work. Posting the assignment will only get you negative votes (especially with the "fast please" in the title) and end up with your question being deleted. try to change the title to something like `Simulate dice game between two player` and to rewrite the question.